# How to Use javafx.scene.layout.HBox and javafx.scene.control.Label from Clojure

Tags: java, javafx, clojure

I'm developing javafx-project in clojure, but I cannot use these javafx's class : javafx.scene.layout.Hbox, javafx.scene.control.Label and javafx.scene.control.[something without Buttom].

I couldn't find solution of it.

Thank you!

Here is the code

> temp/core.clj

```

```
(ns temp.core
  (:import (javafx.application Application)
       (javafx.scene.text Text Font FontWeight)
       (javafx.scene.control Label TextField PasswordField Button)
       (javafx.scene.layout GridPane HBox)
       (javafx.scene.paint Color)
       (javafx.geometry Pos Insets)
       (javafx.event EventHandler)
       (javafx.stage Stage))
(:gen-class))

(def x (Label. "Hello"))
;; get message 
;; 2. Unhandled clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException
;; 1. Caused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
;; javafx.scene.control.Labeled

(def H (HBox. 8))
;; get message
;; 1. Unhandled java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
;; No matching ctor found for class javafx.scene.layout.HBox
```

```

> project.clj

```
(defproject temp "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
:description "FIXME: write description"
:url "http://example.com/FIXME"
:license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
          :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]]
:main temp.core
:aot [temp.core]
:target-path "target/%s"
:profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

Answer (score 0):

I may find solution (I don't know why this solution is correct attribution)

Here is the solution

```
(ns temp.core
 (:import (javafx.application Application)
   (javafx.scene.text Text Font FontWeight)
   (javafx.scene.control Label TextField PasswordField Button)
   (javafx.scene.layout GridPane HBox)
   (javafx.scene.paint Color)
   (javafx.geometry Pos Insets)
   (javafx.event EventHandler)
   (javafx.stage Stage))
(:gen-class))

(defn x [] (Label. "Hello"))

(defn H [] (HBox. 8))
;; return error in 'lein run' : 
;; java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching ctor found for class 
;; javafx.scene.layout.HBox
```

please tell me why this solution works correctly

Answer (score 0):

There is a little more that you have to do in terms of initializing the JavaFX run-time system and starting it up. Here's a very small project that does so.

Here's a project file for Leiningen. It is not significantly different from what you have.

```
(defproject fxdemo "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]]
  :aot :all
  :main fxdemo.core)
```

And a very small program that just shows the version of the JavaFX subsystem.

```
(ns fxdemo.core
  (:gen-class
    :extends javafx.application.Application)
  (:import (javafx.application Application)
           (javafx.scene.layout HBox)
           (javafx.scene.control Label)
           (javafx.scene Scene)
           (javafx.stage Stage)))

(defn -start
  "Build the application interface and start it all up. Called by the
  JavaFX runtime."
  [this stage]

  (let [ver (System/getProperty "javafx.runtime.version")
        lbl (Label. (str "JavaFX Version: " ver))
        root (HBox.)
        scene (Scene. root 250 150)]

    (.add (.getChildren root) lbl)

    (doto ^Stage stage
      (.setScene scene)
      (.setTitle "fxdemo")
      (.show))))

(defn -main
  "Start up the GUI part of the application."
  [& args]
  (Application/launch fxdemo.core args))
```

On my system, executing `lein run` brings up this window:

[image]

You can't really use the pieces of the framework, like `HBox` and `Label` independently of the framework. If you look at the `(gen-class...` statement, you need your main program to extend the JavaFX `Application` class. To initialize the JavaFX subsystem, you need to use the `Application/launch...` method, usually in you program entry function, as shown. (There are exceptions and other ways to do this, but they are too complicated to explain here. This is the easiest/safest way to do it.) By the time the `-start` method is called by the JavaFX subsystem, things are mostly initialized and ready to go.

Also, notice the hyphen character, "-", preceding the `main` and `start` function names, these are needed as part of the interop between Java and Clojure.